# React Native — Infinite Scroll Pagination with FlatList

Tags: react-native

I am doing Infinite Scroll Pagination for loading more data using react-native.

Data loads properly but I want to show bottom indicator for more data loading and no more data.

I tried this but it still not showing bottom indicator while loading data.

The code I tried-

```
const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
const [hasMoreData, setHasMoreData] = useState(true);
```

useEffect()

```
useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, [page, searchText]);

    const fetchData = async () => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(
                `https://dummy-api.php?search=${searchText}&page=${page}`
            );
            const data = response.data.data;

            if (page === 1) {
                setFilteredOptions(data);
            } else {
                setFilteredOptions((prevData) => [...prevData, ...data]);
            }

            if (data.length === 0) {
                setHasMoreData(false);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
        }
        setIsLoading(false);
    };
```

renderItems()-

```
const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
        <TouchableOpacity
            key={item.id}
        >
            <Text style={styles.optionText}>{item.name}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );

    const renderFooter = () => {
        if (!isLoading) return null;

        if (!hasMoreData) {
            return (
                <View>
                    <Text>No more data</Text>
                </View>
            );
        }

        return (
            <View>
                <ActivityIndicator />
            </View>
        );
    };
```

FlatList-

```
<FlatList
                    data={filteredOptions}
                    renderItem={renderItem}
                    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
                    onEndReached={fetchData}
                    onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
                    ListFooterComponent={renderFooter}
                    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                />
```

Is there anything I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I may not be following correctly here, but you want to show an indicator when more is loading in infinite scroll?

If so, you have Null return when loading is false, you should return a component when loading is true.